# Rustlang structopt How to set the home directory

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, structopt

I am using the crate [structopt](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.17/structopt/#environment-variable-fallback) for my cli program. I want to set home directory as default, if output dir in args not passed. Below is my code, please suggest me how i can implement.

```
Command.rs

pub enum Command {
   
    #[structopt(name = "init")]
    Init(InitCmd), 
}
impl Command {
    /// Wrapper around `StructOpt::from_args` method.
    pub fn from_args() -> Self {
        <Self as StructOpt>::from_args()
    }
}
```

```
mod commands;
pub use commands::Command;

fn main(){
    match Command::from_args() {
       Command::Init(cmd) => {
           println!("{:?}", cmd.execute())
       },
   }
 
 }
```

```
impl InitCmd {
    /// Run the command
    pub fn execute(&self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`structopt` fields can take default values, but there is also [an ENV fallback](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.17/structopt/#environment-variable-fallback) which will go and get a default value from the envvar if the option is not provided explicitely.

If you can assume running on a POSIX system, then HOME will be set to the current user's home.

If you can *not* assume POSIX, then I think there are two ways:

- you can define the option as, well, an `Option`. If unspecified it will be set to `None`, and at use-site you can just swap out the `None` for the user's homedir
- define a custom type with all the right bits such that it defaults to the homedir if unspecified (see the structopt doc for how to do that, it involves `FromStr` and optionally `Default` and `ToString`)

Either way, you can use [dirs::home_dir](https://docs.rs/dirs/3.0.1/dirs/fn.home_dir.html) to get the home directory.

Comment: thanks for your replay, i was thinking, is it possible to create function to get home directory, then can pass that function name inside the structopt has vaule ?